# Smack android incoming onStanza is different from debugger

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

The Gajim client on windows and smack debbuger return this kind of stanza, same as the one in the xmpp specs.

```
<message id='aeb213' to='juliet@capulet.lit/chamber'>
  <result xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:2' queryid='f27' id='28482-98726-73623'>
    <forwarded xmlns='urn:xmpp:forward:0'>
      <delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' stamp='2010-07-10T23:08:25Z'/>
      <message xmlns='jabber:client' from="witch@shakespeare.lit" to="macbeth@shakespeare.lit">
        <body>Hail to thee</body>
      </message>
    </forwarded>
  </result>
</message>
```

yet on smack in `onStanza` it returns this one:

```
<message to="juliet@capulet.lit/chamber" from="juliet@capulet.lit/chamber">
  <result xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:0">
    <body>Hail to thee</body>
    <stanza-id/>
    <delay/>
    <archived/>
    <data/>
  </result>
</message>
```

How do you fix this? Here's some parts of the code.

```
public class XmppServiceSmackImpl implements XmppService, StanzaListener, ConnectionListener {
    XmppServiceListener xmppServiceListener;
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(XmppServiceSmackImpl.class.getName());

    XMPPTCPConnection connection;
    String password;

    public XmppServiceSmackImpl(XmppServiceListener xmppServiceListener) {
        this.xmppServiceListener = xmppServiceListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void setup(String jid, String password, String authMethod, String hostname, Integer port) {
        final String[] jidParts = jid.split("@");
        String[] serviceNameParts = jidParts[1].split("/");
        String serviceName = serviceNameParts[0];

        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder confBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .setServiceName(serviceName)
                .setUsernameAndPassword(jidParts[0], password)
                .setConnectTimeout(3000)
                //.setDebuggerEnabled(true)
                .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.required);

        if (serviceNameParts.length>1){
            confBuilder.setResource(serviceNameParts[1]);
        } else {
            confBuilder.setResource(Long.toHexString(Double.doubleToLongBits(Math.random())));
        }
        if (hostname != null){
            confBuilder.setHost(hostname);
        }
        if (port != null){
            confBuilder.setPort(port);
        }
        if (trustedHosts.contains(hostname) || (hostname == null && trustedHosts.contains(serviceName))){
            confBuilder.setCustomSSLContext(UnsafeSSLContext.INSTANCE.getContext());
        }
        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration connectionConfiguration = confBuilder.build();
        XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(true);
        XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumptionDefault(true);
        connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(connectionConfiguration);

        // Disable automatic roster request
        Roster roster = Roster.getInstanceFor(connection);
        roster.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(false);
        roster.setSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.manual);

        connection.addAsyncStanzaListener(this, null);
        connection.addConnectionListener(this);
        connection.addStanzaAcknowledgedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void processPacket(Stanza packet) throws SmackException.NotConnectedException {
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Received stanza: " + packet);
        this.xmppServiceListener.onStanza(packet);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

belongs to XEP-0280
In SMACK, it's an experimental feature.
you need additional library in your build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.2.0"
}
```

Before you do any thing with SMACK, you have to initialize experimental feature:

```
new ExperimentalInitializer().initialize();
```

By the way, provider is a plugin-like stanza handler
When you want to use customized stanza between your client and server.
You have to write your own provider to parse it into extension element that under Message object.
Take a look at ProviderManager.

Comment: i upgraded to 4.2.0 and it solved this because of the newly added mam support and its providers.

but good to know about custom providers